# How to change value of an object with keyup?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Here is the frontend, so when a user key in couple of value, the submit button will insert the value into an object.

[image]

Here we already got our object like this

```
0: {name: "a", club: "b"}
1: {name: "c", club: "d"}
```

How can I change 'name'/'club' value from 'a' to any value that I typed in the input with keyup?

Here's the code

```js
var player = [];

function insertData() {
  var name = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value;
  var club = document.querySelector('input[name="club"]').value;
  player.push({
    name,
    club
  });
  onSetDisplay();
}

function onSetDisplay() {
  document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = "";

  for (i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
    var wrapper = onCreateElement('div', null, i);
    var input1 = onCreateElement('input', player[i].name);
    var input2 = onCreateElement('input', player[i].club);

    wrapper.appendChild(input1);
    wrapper.appendChild(input2);

    var deleteBtn = onCreateElement('button', '', "Delete", function () {
      // console.log(this.parentNode)
      player.splice(this.parentNode.getAttribute('data-index'), 1);
      this.parentNode.remove();
    });

    wrapper.appendChild(deleteBtn);

    document.querySelector('.display').appendChild(wrapper);
  }

}

function onCreateElement(element, value, text, ev) {
  var e = document.createElement(element);

  if (element == 'input') {
    e.value = value;
    e.type = 'textfield';
    e.setAttribute('onkeyup', 'editData()');
    e.id = "playerlist";
  } else {
    e.setAttribute('data-index', text)
    e.innerHTML = text;
  }

  if (typeof ev == 'function') {
    e.addEventListener('click', ev);
  }

  return e;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name"></input>
<input type="text" name="club"></input><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="insertData();"></input>
<br><br>
<div class="display">
</div>
```

Comment: So, do you want to achieve the same functionality without submit button?

Comment: Yes correct, basically I want to replace object value with keyup on the corresponding input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing the implementation of `editData()` function, I modified your `JS`, please have a look below, I hope it will meet to your expectation,

```
var player = [];

function insertData() {
  var name = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value;
  var club = document.querySelector('input[name="club"]').value;
  player.push({
    name,
    club
  });
  onSetDisplay();
}

function onSetDisplay() {
  document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = "";

  for (i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
    var wrapper = onCreateElement('div', null, i);
    var input1 = onCreateElement('input', player[i].name, '', 'name_'+i, i);
    var input2 = onCreateElement('input', player[i].club, '', 'club_'+i, i);

    wrapper.appendChild(input1);
    wrapper.appendChild(input2);

    var deleteBtn = onCreateElement('button', '', "Delete", "", "", function() {
      // console.log(this.parentNode)
      player.splice(this.parentNode.getAttribute('data-index'), 1);
      this.parentNode.remove();
    });

    wrapper.appendChild(deleteBtn);

    document.querySelector('.display').appendChild(wrapper);
  }

}

function onCreateElement(element, value, text, id, index, ev) {
  var e = document.createElement(element);

  if (element == 'input') {
    e.value = value;
    e.type = 'textfield';
    e.setAttribute('onkeyup', 'editData('+id+')');
    e.id = id;
  } else {
    e.setAttribute('data-index', text)
    e.innerHTML = text;
  }

  if (typeof ev == 'function') {
    e.addEventListener('click', ev);
  }

  return e;
}

// added this editData method, 
function editData(id) {
    console.log("id: ", id.id, id.value);
}
```

**Check Below Attached Screenshot with result.**
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, sort of like this. But how can I just use data-index from the parent div of the input instead of id?

Comment: If you just focus on parent div of input, you are already passing, index so utilize that index as per your need